# Installing dropbox (and use Kirby CMS) on openshift

Tags: installation, dropbox, openshift, kirby

I'm trying to find a way to integrate Kirby CMS with Dropbox running on Openshift using these tutorials:
http://getkirby.com/blog/kirby-meets-dropbox
http://getkirby.com/forum/how-to/topic:561

I already get stuck installing Dropbox, since I assume I don't really have permission while SSHing:
http://www.dropbox.com/install?os=lnx

**So my question: Is there even any way of achieving all that greatness? If no, not even if we get reaaaally creative? If NO, why not? If yes, how?**

Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 1):

I have no experience with Kirby, but here's how to get Dropbox working on Openshift.

The following is a combination of doing a Dropbox install on a server and doing it in a non-standard location. Everything gets done in $OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR because that's where you have write privileges.

First, make sure you're in $OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR

```
cd $OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR
```

Next, download the appropriate version of Dropbox:

```
wget -O - "https://www.dropbox.com/download?plat=lnx.x86" | tar xzf -
```

This should give you the .dropbox-dist folder in $OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR.

Next, tell Dropbox to start the installation process, but tell it that your home directory is actually the $OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR:

```
HOME=$OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR ./.dropbox-dist/dropboxd start -i
```

Follow the instructions to link your Dropbox account to the Openshift server. After it's linked, it should start syncing everything in your Dropbox account to $OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR/Dropbox. This might be a bad thing for you because you have too much data in your Dropbox account. If so, then you should exclude folders.

You can do that with the CLI script that Dropbox provides. Still in $OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR, download it:

```
wget -O dropbox.py "https://www.dropbox.com/download?dl=packages/dropbox.py"
```

Make sure it's executable:

```
chmod +x dropbox.py
```

You need to run it the same way you would Dropbox:

```
HOME=$OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR $OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR/dropbox.py -h
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to download/compile/install things into your OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR (app-root/data) on your gear by using something like ./configure --prefix=~/app-root/data/dropbox, i tried that but i ran into missing the nautilus-whatever package, which i assume you could download and install in the same fashion, but i did not try past that point.  As long as whatever you are running can be installed into the app-root/data, and does not require root permissions to run, you should be able to do it.  If you get it going, you could also create a downloadable cartridge to run install it more easily.